# Как очистить строку в CODESYS 3.5 библиотека PRO_JSON?

Tags: json

Для формирования JSON строки использую библиотеку PRO_JSON, функцию STRUCT_TO_JSON.
Проблема: если предыдущая строка была длиннее, чем та, которую формирую, её "хвост" остается.
У функции есть метод ClearString, но при попытке запуска, программа валится.

```
VAR
    sequence: STRING;
    STRUCT_TO_JSON:PRO_JSON.STRUCT_TO_JSON;
    indx: int;
END_VAR
////////////////////////////
STRUCT_TO_JSON.ClearString();
```

Подскажите, что можно предпринять?

Comment: Что за язык программирования? Добавьте тег. И валится то с ошибкой какой-то? Добавьте полный текст ошибки в вопрос.